# Unable to change mysql user password using update statement

Tags: mysql, passwords

I am able to change mysql user password using set password method and alter user statement. But, failed with update user command.

> mysql> UPDATE USER SET PASSWORD=PASSWORD('George$987') where USER = 'george' and host='localhost';
>   ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('George$987') where USER = 'george' and host='localhost'' at line 1

What is the error in my below statement:

> UPDATE USER SET PASSWORD=PASSWORD('George$987') where USER = 'george' and host='localhost';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you are using MySQL 8.0. You must use [SET PASSWORD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/set-password.html) in MySQL 8.0.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/encryption-functions.html#function_password says:

> - PASSWORD(str)
>
>   This function was removed in MySQL 8.0.11.